# button is not taking any filter in first click, in second it is working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, user-interface

I am calling `API` and loading data into `table` when pages gets loaded using `useEffect()`. but once page gets loaded user can resubmit by clicking button by using some filter.

[image]

the problem is user need to click twice then only filter is working. I am using formik to create the form and button.

```
 const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);     
const [filters,setFilters]=useState({
          certificateNo:"",
          protoColNo:"",
          requestStatus:"",
          sponser:"",
          country:"",
          researchTitle:"",
          noOfSubjects:"",
          startDate:"",
          endDate:"",
      })
    
        useEffect(() => {
         fetchData(page)
        }, [page]);
    
      const fetchData =async( page:any) =>{
          const { certificateNo, protoColNo, requestStatus, researchTitle, sponser,country,noOfSubjects,startDate,endDate} = filters;
          const param = {
              ...(certificateNo && { certificateNo: certificateNo }),
              ...(protoColNo && { protoColNo: protoColNo }),
              ...(requestStatus && { requestStatus: requestStatus }),
              ...(researchTitle && {researchTitle: researchTitle}),
              ...(sponser && { sponser: sponser }),
              ...(country && { country: country }),
              ...(noOfSubjects && { noOfSubjects: noOfSubjects }),
              ...(startDate && { startDate: startDate }),
              ...(endDate && { endDate: endDate }),
          };
           console.log('Inside fetch data');
             const {data} = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/certificates?page=${page}`,{
                  params: param,
              })
              console.log("Inside data :"+data.data);
              setResponse(data.data);  
              setFlag(true); 
              setLastPage(data.meta.last_page);
       }
```

below code is calling `fetchData`

```
  const handleSubmit =async (values:any)=>{
           console.log("Inside the handle Submit");
           setFilters(values); //Here I am setting filter value.
           fetchData(page);
        }
```

Here button is defined inside `formik` . what mistake I am doing?

```
    <Formik
            initialValues={formInitialSchema}
            validationSchema={formValidationSchema}
            onSubmit= {handleSubmit}>
    <button className="btn btn-success btn-block " type="submit">
   </Formik>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is from your `handleSubmit` function. You are trying to fetch data using the filter values but you set the filter values in the form that fetches the data. The main issue is React's `setState` is asynchronous and the state might have not changed before `fetchData(page)` is called

```
 const handleSubmit =async (values:any)=>{
       console.log("Inside the handle Submit");
       setFilters(values); //Here I am setting filter value.
       fetchData(page);
    }
```

You need to create your filter values the moment they are selected. This is mean making an assumption to give you a hint.

You would need to pass your filter query to `fetchData` in your `handleSubmit` and send the request rather than setting the values in the function. Example below

```
const handleSubmit =async (values:any)=> {
   fetchData(page, values);
}
```

The in your `fetchData` function, you refactor to look like this

```
const fetchData = async(page:any, filters) =>{
      const { certificateNo, protoColNo, requestStatus, researchTitle, sponser,country,noOfSubjects,startDate,endDate} = filters;
      const param = {
          ...(certificateNo && { certificateNo: certificateNo }),
          ...(protoColNo && { protoColNo: protoColNo }),
          ...(requestStatus && { requestStatus: requestStatus }),
          ...(researchTitle && {researchTitle: researchTitle}),
          ...(sponser && { sponser: sponser }),
          ...(country && { country: country }),
          ...(noOfSubjects && { noOfSubjects: noOfSubjects }),
          ...(startDate && { startDate: startDate }),
          ...(endDate && { endDate: endDate }),
      };
       console.log('Inside fetch data');
         const {data} = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/certificates?page=${page}`,{
              params: param,
          })
          console.log("Inside data :"+data.data);
          setResponse(data.data);  
          setFlag(true); 
          setLastPage(data.meta.last_page);
   }
```